# Vue.js2 style binding not working

Tags: vuejs2

I'm pass a collection, `rows`, as an array of objects.

Inside the v-for:

```
<th class="line-checkboxes" @click="row.checked = !row.checked" >
   <div :class="{'line-checked' : row.checked }">
      <i class="line-checkboxes-icon"></i>
   </div>
</th
```

However, the class property is no reactive. 
What could be the reason for it?

Comment: Do you set an initial value for `row.checked`?

Comment: No, the default us undefined. and then the value is changed to true/false (checked it already, the @click is ok)

Comment: it should not be undefined. It should be null or false... in other words this won't work if `row` doesn't have a `checked` property

Comment: The value is probably getting set correctly, but Vue can't react to a property value change if the property was undefined beforehand. See the first item in the first section here: https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/